# How to dispose a view which has been created with Platform.CreateRenderer ( )

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, dispose

I'm looking for the correct way to dispose a UIView (iOS) or ViewGroup (Android) which has been created by Platform.CreateRenderer(...).

In short, I use this as a extension to a ListView and want to provide a Xamarin.Forms.View which I use while the list is refreshing.

```
public class MyListView : ListView
{
    //refresh view which will be shown while refreshing the list
    public View RefreshContent { get; set; }
}
```

In iOS I'm currently doing this in my MyListViewRenderer:

```
this.renderer = Platform.CreateRenderer(this.Element.RefreshContent);
Platform.SetRenderer(this.Element.RefreshContent, this.renderer);

this.AddSubview(this.renderer.NativeView);
```

And to dispose I try this:

```
this.renderer?.NativeView?.RemoveFromSuperview();
this.renderer?.NativeView?.Dispose();
this.renderer?.Dispose();
this.renderer = null;
```

Does that dispose anything, including further subviews etc.? What about Android?

Comment: I don't believe you have to worry about disposing that view. Xamarin will dispose that view automatically as soon as it's garbage collector kicks in. It applies to iOS as well as to Android.

Comment: Xamarin theirselves are heavily using Dispose - if you have a look at the source code of Xamarin.Forms. This mostly is important for Android.

Comment: everyone says something different unfortunately (as well as the code does look different even in Xamarin examples). I had recently a 30 minute call with Xamarin trainer and we were basically talking only about disposing. He (in short) told me to worry only about disposing bitmaps everything else should be handled by the Xamarin framework.